# Navigation Term Set takes some time to settle?

Tags: navigation, term, managed-navigation

I'm currently provisioning Navigation Term Set programatically and then programatically assigning that as the Global Navigation of my site. I am using SharePoint 2013.

Problem is, it seems to not be attached properly immediately. I receive an error that says the Navigation Term Set was not assigned properly.

I think this is because it is not immediately recognized by SharePoint? I notice that there is something like a "new" icon on the Navigation term set. After a few times of assigning / re-assigning the navigation by switching from Managed Metadata to Structural, I notice that it the icon of the Navigation Term Set changes (grayish icon). Once it changes, I can then successfully assign it.

Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had my scope to site. I think it should be to web, I changed it and it worked properly now.